# Liferay IDE hook for organization

Tags: plugins, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

How I can create a hook using eclipse IDE to customize organization form details and make custom attribute required what I must do to begin?

How to make custom attribute accept arabic characters ?

Is there any way to add organization portlet for organizations members and users?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question.

Comment: i need to make custom fields validation 
and when submit create organization form it doesn't accept arabic language

how this issue can be done ?

Comment: Please post separate questions instead of combining different questions into one. It helps people answering your questions one by one and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks.